# how to take server database backup with data in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

My data base is in US Server and i want to take the database backup with data using sql server 2005 or sql wizard is it possible. and after that i want to store the database in my local system

Answer (score 2):

Please see the documentation: [How to: Back Up a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Basic backup-restore in SSMS:

Right click database in the Object Explorer and click Tasks -> Backup

[image]

Set options in the Backup Database dialog:

[image]

In the wanted instance, right click Databases node in the Object Explorer pane and select Restore Database:

[image]

Browse to your backup file and click OK:

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just take a regular backup :

```
backup database database_name to disk = 'D:\backups\database_name.bak'
with init, stats =10
```

and then move that backup to your local machine and restore it

```
restore database database_name from disk = 'D:\backups\database_name.bak'
with stats =10, recovery,
move 'logical_file_data' to 'physical file location_data.mdf'
move 'logical_file_log' to 'physical file location_log.ldf'
```

You can even zip the backup or compress using third party tools as well.

**Caution:** Unless the database backup does not contain any sensitive data and it does not violate your client or company's agreements, you should be fine. Always de-sensitize the data before you start playing with it.